# JavaScript for video source is causing jssor slider to display all caption at once

Tags: javascript

I have created a website with a Jssor slider which, when page is loading, starts displaying all slider captions for a second before functioning normal. After removing bit by bit from the page to see what actually causes this, I found out that a video link loading from another website via some JavaScript is the reason for this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vm_open.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">client="1111"; openthis="A_e2343ccc"; lang="en"; menuaccess=false; autoplay=false; width=450; vm_open();</script>
```

Originally, the fist script line was loaded from the video website as well but I managed to put the script onto my server to avoid prolonged loading via internet. While this shortened the loading time, the result is still not satisfactory.

Is it possible to add a delay to that specific function in order to have the jssor slider load first before the video is loaded to avoid the scrambling of the slider caption?

I have read through countless of posts here but could not manage to get the result.
Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: somehow the script got cut, so here again
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vm_open.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">client="5822"; openthis="A_e2777ccc"; lang="en"; menuaccess=false; autoplay=false; width=450; vm_open();</script>

Answer (score 0):

I guess you added custom content (video) to slide.

Re: is it possible to add a delay to that specific function in order to have the jssor slider load first...?

After initialization of jssor slider, you can still add content to slide.

```
var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(...;

//add content (video) to slide manually by script. for example,
//$("#slide-0").append("html code");
```